# how to reciever coordinates through sms and shown in google maps.... in android

Tags: android, google-maps, broadcastreceiver, sms, coordinates

I am trying to send coordinates from one phone to another, sender send its coordinates when a buton is pressed..... recievers is also receiving these coordinates but doesnot show them in google maps, i dont where is the problem (but i think intent inside broadcast receiver is not starting because toast above is showing)

my main activity :- (from where i am sending sms successfully)

```
/*----------Listener class to get coordinates ------------- */
    private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {

            editLocation.setText("");
            pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Location changed : Lat: " +
                            loc.getLatitude()+ " Lng: " + loc.getLongitude(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            //for showLocation method
            Latitude=loc.getLatitude();
            Longitude=loc.getLongitude();
            //

            String longitude = "Longitude: " +loc.getLongitude();
            Log.v(TAG, longitude);
            String latitude = "Latitude: " +loc.getLatitude();
            Log.v(TAG, latitude);

    /*----------to get City-Name from coordinates ------------- */
            String cityName=null;
            Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());
            List<Address>  addresses;
            try {
                addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude(), 1);
                if (addresses.size() > 0)
                    System.out.println(addresses.get(0).getLocality());
                cityName=addresses.get(0).getLocality();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            String s = longitude+"\n"+latitude + "\n\nMy Currrent City is: "+cityName;
            editLocation.setText(s);
            String phoneNumber="+xxxxxxxxxx";
            // to send sms
            Intent intent = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse( "sms:" + phoneNumber ) );
            intent.putExtra( "sms_body",loc.getLongitude()+"\n"+loc.getLatitude() );
            startActivity( intent );
```

my broadcast receiver class is as follows:- (when sms is received, following code does show the toast with coordinates and everything but why it is not showing it in google maps, i dont know..... it acts like its not working after taost statement....... i just want that after toast is shown, google maps opens and show these coordinates

```
package com.example.mishaal.samplegetcoordinates;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class SmsBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    final SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    public static final String SMS_CONTENT = "sms_content";
    public String longitude,latitude;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO: This method is called when the BroadcastReceiver is receiving
        // an Intent broadcast.
        final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        try
        {
            if(bundle != null)
            {
                final Object[] pduObjects = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                for (int i=0; i<pduObjects.length; i++)
                {
                    SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pduObjects[i]);
                    String number = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
                    String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();
                    //Toast.makeText(context,"without executing if statement" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(message);
                    latitude=scanner.nextLine();
                    longitude=scanner.nextLine();
                    scanner.close();
                    Toast.makeText(context,"Sender No:" + number + "\nMessage " + message , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=" + ("" + latitude + "," + longitude + "")));
                    try {
                        context.startActivity(intent);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                   }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("SmsReceiver", "Exception smsReceiver" + e);
        }
    }
}
```

i am a newbie, so plz help by giving code snippets, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Once you have received the coordinates as a toast you need to parse them and send an intent request to be opened in the Google Maps app.

*After creating the Intent, you can request that the system launch the related app in a number of ways. A common method is to pass the Intent to the startActivity() method. The system will launch the necessary app — in this case Google Maps — and start the corresponding Activity.*

```
// Create a Uri from an intent string. Use the result to create an Intent.
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("google.streetview:cbll=46.414382,10.013988");

// Create an Intent from gmmIntentUri. Set the action to ACTION_VIEW
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
// Make the Intent explicit by setting the Google Maps package
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");

// Attempt to start an activity that can handle the Intent
startActivity(mapIntent);
```

Read the official documentation on [Google Maps Intent](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/intents?hl=en).